# Как получить доступ к классу или функции, которая объявлена ниже по коду?

Tags: c++

Код класса полностью описан, но ниже, чем вызов методов из этого класса. По сути у меня есть грузовик, который должен уметь добавлять сам себя в очередь на погрузку на базе, причём база должна иметь возможность этот грузовик удалять из очереди после ряда махинаций.

Comment: для класса можно использовать предварительное объявление и использовать это предварительное объявление для объявления указателя или ссылки на инстанс класса, а так же для inline методов другого класса которые не будут использовать операторы "." и "->" от ссылки или указателя соответственно, для функций так не сработает, вообще страный вопрос, будто вы намереваетесь объявлять разные функции и классы в одном хидере, что не особо то правильно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Объявите** класс и его методы раньше места, где они используются. А **определите** после.

*Объявление класса*:

```
class class_name
{
    void method1();
};
```

*Определение метода*:

```
void class_name::method1()
{
    // код метода
}
```

---

На практике, объявление отдельных классов  выносят в `class_name.h` (хэдер), а методы определяются в `class_name.cpp`. Чтобы добавить объявление `class_name` в другой файл используется команда препроцессора `include`:

```
#include "class_name.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю в ответу пользователя Андрей
Во-первых, имя класс лучше писать с большой буквы, а во-вторвых желательно писать спецификаторы (public, protected, private), хотя не обязательно, по умолчанию private, просто я думаю что Ваш метод будет вызываться клиентом, соответственно он должен быть не private, а public:

```
class ClassName
{
public:
    void method1();
};
```

Comment: С какой буквы писать — большой или маленькой — зависит от стиля, принятого в команде/компании/проекте.

Comment: Про public/private - замечание правильное. А про регистр бука Андрей уже ответил - это дело стиля, личного или корпоративного.

Answer (score 0):

для класса можно использовать предварительное объявление и использовать это предварительное объявление для объявления указателя или ссылки на инстанс класса, а так же для inline методов ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫХ внутри определения другого класса которые не будут использовать операторы "." и "->" от ссылки или указателя соответственно, для функций так не сработает, вообще страный вопрос, будто вы намереваетесь объявлять разные функции и классы в одном хидере, что не особо то правильно.

```
class Foo;

class Bar {
    private: 
        Foo* foo_;
    public:
        void setFoo( Foo* foo ) { // inline метод
            foo_ = foo; 
        }
};
```

после предварительного объявления вы можете включить хидер с полным определением класса Foo в файл .cpp для методов класса Bar